# Directory of an exported zfs pool comes back after removal

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nas, zfs

When i export a zfs pool, the folder where the the pool was mounted still exists with only some of the datasets the pool has contained before.

Before re-importing I delete the directory where the pool was mounted via

```
sudo rm -rf /tank
```

Then the directory seems to be deleted. But after a short amount of time the directory shows up again with the exact same datasets, that were there right after export.

The pool was created via...

```
sudo zpool create tank mirror sda sdb
```

Output of zpool status:

```
config@ubuntu-nas:/tank$ zpool status
  pool: storage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:39:53 with 0 errors on Sun Jun 28 19:23:35 2020
config:

        NAME                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage                              ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                           ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST2000VN004-2E4164_Z529RBWZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST2000VN004-2E4164_Z529RDW1  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: torrent_media
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        torrent_media  ONLINE       0     0     0
          sda          ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdb          ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I tried to umount the pool:

```
sudo umount /tank
umount: /tank: not mounted.
```

I tried to zfs unmount the pool

```
sudo zfs unmount tank
cannot open 'tank': dataset does not exist
```

Output of sudo mount
only entries containing zfs
and in the output there were no entries containing "tank"

```
/torrent_media on /torrent_media type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)

/storage/docker on /docker type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
/storage on /storage type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
/storage/nextcloud on /storage/nextcloud type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
/storage/torrent_media on /storage/torrent_media type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
/storage/sam_personal on /storage/sam_personal type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "_But after a short amount of time the directory shows up again with the exact same datasets_" - are you sure? or is it just the hierarchy that is re-created, perhaps by some service writing files there...? When the pool is not present (i.e: not shown in the output of `zpool status`), use `df -hT "${dir}"` to see what filesystem a particular directory is on. I suspect it'll be your rootfs.

Comment: "_in the output there were no entries containing "tank"_" - note that your pool is called `storage`... not `tank`... Is this a different pool that we should be ignoring?

Comment: I re-imported the pool (former tank) as storage to access my files... but i still cant remove the folder /tank

Answer (score 0):

Attie is right!

> Blockquote
> or is it just the hierarchy that is re-created, perhaps by some service writing files there...?

Thank you! I feel kinda dumb, I didn't see that.

i ran:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

to kill all my containers.